Support for order by /limit with Bulk API 2.0 V2
I'm asking a question regarding SFDC Bulk API 2.0. As per the limitations mentioned here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/queries.htm#limits, using limit or order by might result in query timeouts and disables PK chunking.
If we absolutely have to use those two functions, is the only option to use the older bulk API? Or is there any workaround available for us to use the new bulk API without seeing timeouts?

Why do you absolutely have to use those two functions

Our existing queries use them, and we need those to order/limit our query result.

...your existing queries use them with Bulk API 1.0? If so, then you already know your choices. Choice #3: examine the need for LIMIT/ORDER BY - in a bulk query, this is unusual.

Well, I'd almost question why the 1.0 API let customers use those functions in the first place if it's supposed to be unusual. Nevertheless, thank you.
